# PHP preg_match_all named groups issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, regex-group

I'm trying to get grouped matches from the following URI:

```
route: "/user/{user}/{action}"
input: "/user/someone/news"
```

What's the appropriate regex for this? I've been searching myself sour for the past couple of hours...

I've tried something like this, but no result :(

```
~\/app\/user\/(?P<user>[.*]+)\/(?P<action>[.*]+)~
```

I get the groups back in the matches array, but no results based on the input inside the groups.

Desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "someone"
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => "someone"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "news"
        )

    [action] => Array
        (
            [0] => "news"
        )
)
```

To clarify with an example:

My controller has the following route: `/app/user/{username}/{action}`
The request URI from the browser is: `/app/user/john/news`

How do I match that request URI against that route using a regex patter while catching the variables between the brackets?

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match (give exact examples) and what are the desired results. (give examples).

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to match the input as stated above to the route using a regex pattern and capturing the pieces between the brackets.

route: /user/{username}
input: /user/john-smith
regex: ?

Comment: There's a lot of things going wrong here or things that can be improved. **1)** Your regex starts with `\/app` while the input doesn't start with `/app`. **2)** You're using `~` as delimiter but you're escaping slashes ? Why ? Just use `/user/etc...`. **3)** You're using `[.*]`, putting `.*` in a character class `[]` will make it's regex notation useless so `[.*]` matches either a dot or an asterisk. I don't think you want that ... I think you want something like [`user/(?P<user>[^/]+)/(?P<action>[^/]+)`](http://regex101.com/r/bC3yO8). Have fun !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/user/(?P<user>[^/]+)/(?P<action>[^/]+)
```

http://regex101.com/r/gL1aS2

Just to explain a couple problems with your original regex:

- `[.*]+` means a positive number of occurrences of a dot and an asterisk only, example: `*.*.*` or `.` or `......`; `[^/]+` describes a positive number of any characters but slashes.
- No need to escape slashes, as they're not special characters when you're using `~` as delimiters.
- Your regex also required */app* at the beginning, which wasn't present in your string.

Comment: This is it; however, I would use `[^/]+` instead of `.+` (even though both work).  Also, it should be noted that the forward slashes weren't escaped since OP used `~` as a delimiter.

Comment: Yay, it works! Thanks a lot :) That turned out to be a lot simpeler than the things I've tried to do :p

Comment: @SamSullivan Good point. I've updated the answer. Harold, I'm glad I could help.